# Microsoft CRM Dataverse inconsistent connection

Tags: c#, .net-core, dynamics-crm

I am currently working with an application that is connecting to an off-prem instance of CRM Dataverse. We are using the API to insert and extract user data from a .NET Core 3.1 web application. However, we keep running into an issue of the connection to be forcibly closed and getting the following logged:

```
 Microsoft.PowerPlatform.Dataverse.Client.Utils.DataverseConnectionException: Failed to connect to Dataverse
 ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (An error occurred while sending the request.)
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

This seems to happen randomly with no pattern. Most of the time, the data that we are passing in has no issues but sometimes it throws this error and we can't add or update the user.

We have tried using `TLS 1.2`, `TLS 1.3` and adding `RequireNewInstance=true;` to our connection to no avail. Even after a lot of exploration on various sites, we have yet to find a solution to make the connection more consistent.

Does anyone have any recommendations of solutions to this problem?

Comment: This can be caused by so many things. How is your web app connecting? HttpClient? How many requests are handled per hour/minute? How are connection instances disposed? Authentication technique used? Which end point is accessed (SOAP/OData)? How many concurrent requests? Do you see high resource consumption (e.g. sockets). Could there be firewall components active on the network blocking access or shutting down connections? Etc. etc...

Comment: I had faced similar issues, this might be due to Service Protection API Limits. Please refer following link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/api-limits